# How to $pull from nested array with no fieldnames in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

my arrays in mongoDB are:
slots: Array
0: Array,
1: Array,
2: Array,
etc.

in each array, I have an array of slots
:
"August 15th 2021 00:00"
1
:
"August 15th 2021 00:30"
2
:
"August 15th 2021 01:00"
3
:
"August 15th 2021 01:30"
4
:
"August 15th 2021 02:00"
5
:
"August 15th 2021 02:30"
6
:
"August 15th 2021 03:00"
7
:
"August 15th 2021 03:30"
8
:
"August 15th 2021 04:00"
9
:
"August 15th 2021 04:30"
10
:
"August 15th 2021 05:00"
11
:
"August 15th 2021 05:30"

I try to pull from these but it doesn't work.
my code:

```
  exports.postAvailibility = (req,res)=>{
    const teacherId = req.params.teacherId;
    var slots = req.body.chosenSlots;
    var day = req.body.day
    Teacher.updateOne({_id: teacherId}, { $addToSet: {availibility: slots} }, (err, result)=>{
      if(err){
        return res.json(err)
      } else{
        Teacher.updateOne({_id: teacherId}, {$pull: {"slots.0": slots}}, (err, result)=>{
          if(err){
            return res.json(err)
          } else{
            return res.json("Successfully booked slot")
          }
        } )
      }
    })
  }
```

It adds to the availability field but doesn't pull from slots

Comment: If you can give sample data in, what you want to do, the query you tried, and the data out(how you want them to become).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
const teacherId = req.params.teacherId;
    var slots = req.body.chosenSlots;
    var day = req.body.day
    Teacher.updateOne({_id: teacherId}, { $addToSet: {availability: slots} }, (err, result)=>{
      if(err){
        return res.json(err)
      } else{
        Teacher.updateOne({_id: teacherId}, {$pull: {"slots.$[]": slots}}, (err, result)=>{
          if(err){
            return res.json(err)
          } else{
            return res.json("Successfully booked slot")
          }
        } )
      }
    })
```